# Docker: multistage build for python:2.7-slim

Tags: python, python-2.7, docker

Dockerfile

```
FROM docker as docker
CMD ["bash"]
FROM python:2.7-slim as python
CMD ["bash"]

# base image
FROM ubuntu
COPY --from=docker /usr/local/ /usr/local/
COPY --from=python /usr/local/ /usr/local/

CMD ["ls", "/usr/local/bin"]
```

Then,

```
docker build -t test .
docker run test
```

Output:

```
2to3
docker
docker-containerd
docker-containerd-ctr
docker-containerd-shim
docker-entrypoint.sh
docker-init
docker-proxy
docker-runc
dockerd
easy_install
easy_install-2.7
idle
modprobe
pip
pip2
pip2.7
pydoc
python
python-config
python2
python2-config
python2.7
python2.7-config
smtpd.p
```

great, I see python and docker binaries. But if i try running it..

```
docker run test /usr/local/bin/python --version
/usr/local/bin/python: error while loading shared libraries: libpython2.7.so.1.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

i dont think copying /usr/local alone is sufficient perhaps?
what else do I need to do to get python working in ubuntu?